# Unpack value(s) into variable(s) or None (ValueError: not enough values to unpack)

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

How should an `iterable` be unpacked into a mismatching number of variable(s)?

Too many values:

```
>>> one,two = [1,2,3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

can be ignored with

```
>>> one,two,*_ = [1,2,3,4]  
>>>
```

Note: "[extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)" since Python 3 only. About the [underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python).

How can the opposite case of too few data / more variables:

```
>>> one,two,three = [1,2]   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
>>>
```

be handled, specifically so that the remaining variables are assigned `None` (or some other value)?

Something like this:

```
>>> one,two,three = [1,2] or None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
>>>
```

---

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8857846/1619432 suggests expanding the list:

```
>>> one,two,three = [1,2] + [None]*(3-2)
>>> one   
1
>>> two
2
>>> three
>>>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a more general answer where you can have more than three variables on the left as well?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Yes. The number variables is constant, though.

Comment: Then I don't think it's possible to achieve

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59141795/6260170

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `*` operator and fill an intermediate iterable with that which you're unpacking and fill the remainder with your default value of choice.

```
x = [1, 2]
default_value= None
one, two, three = [*x, *([default_value] * (3 - len(x)))]
```

And a bonus function to handle both cases:

```
def unpack(source, target, default_value=None):
    n = len(source)
    if n < target:
        return [*source, *([default_value] * (target - len(source)))]
    elif n > target:
        return source[0:target]
    else:
        return source
```

Amend to handle non-iterable input as needed.

Answer (score 15):

You can unpack a sequence to three variable using:

```
one, two, *three = [1,2]
```

At this point, `three` will be an empty list.  You can then assign `three` to `None` using an `or` check if three is empty.

```
three = three or None
```

Comment: I think he is looking for a more general answer, where the number of variable on the left can be any quantity greater than or equal to 3

Answer (score 5):

Does this work for you? You can make the `nones` array as big as you need.

```py
nones = [None]*100 # or however many you think you might need
one, two, three, four, five, *_ = [1,2] + nones
```